# Next.js API route AxiosError: socket hang up ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, axios

My code works fine for the first request to my Next.js API route. The request that comes after (without restarting the server) typically gets to the point of "GO4" being logged to the terminal but then after quite some time fails with the following error:

```
AxiosError: socket hang up
    at AxiosError.from (/Users/xyz/Desktop/Projects/xyz/Project/API/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:725:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/Users/xyz/Desktop/Projects/xyz/Project/API/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2467:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/Users/xyz/Desktop/Projects/xyz/Project/API/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:518:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

How may I fix this ?

---

Next.js API route code:

```
import Cors from 'cors'
import FormData from 'form-data';

const axios = require('axios');
const form = new FormData();

const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'HEAD']
})

export const config = {
  api: {
    responseLimit: false
  }
}


export default async function handler(req, res) {

  try {

    const imageBuffers = [];

    await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);

    const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

    for (const image of body.images) {
      
      const response = await axios.get(image, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
      if(((response.headers['content-type']).match(/(image)+\//g)).length == 0){
        res.send("Invalid image URL");
      }
      imageBuffers.push(Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'));
    }

    form.append('...', body.title);

    for (const i in imageBuffers) {
      form.append('images', imageBuffers[i], 'Image'+i+'.jpg');
    }

    const response = await axios.post(
      'url',
      form,
      {
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              'Authorization': 'Bearer xyz'
          }
      }
    );
    console.log("DATA: "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));

  } catch(err) {

    console.log("ERROR");
    console.error(err);
    res.send(err);

  }

}


function runMiddleware(req,res,fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result)
      }
      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}
```